# need to change attribute value

Tags: jquery

I am asking this question again but hopefully being a little more clearer. See this thread for more info

[javascript error in IE8 compatibitlity mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056326/javascript-error-in-ie8-compatibitlity-mode)

I have the following markup on the page of which I cannot change directly. I need to change the the function called from "change_option" to "changeoption". How can this be done for each selectbox. I have not shown the options as they are not relevant in this case.

```
<select onChange="change_option('SELECT___100E___7',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" name="SELECT___100E___7">
<select onChange="change_option('SELECT___123___6',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" name="SELECT___123___6">
<select onChange="change_option('SELECT___584E___52',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" name="SELECT___584E___52">
```

Comment: As an alternative, have you considered just adding `function change_option(a,b) { changeoption(a,b); }` to your page? I note that was suggested in your previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $('select').each(
        function(){
              $(this).change(
                  function() {
                      changeoption(this.name,$(this).val());
                  }
              ).attr("onchange",function(){           
                               changeoption(this.name,this.options[this.selectedIndex].value); 
                     }
              );            
        } 
    );
});
```

Comment: Wow, this works in IE8 comp mode, I love pink floyd BTW. I just need to change the selector to $("select[name^=SELECT___]").each but it works perfectly. I need to look at this more carefully to understand how and why it works. Thanks!!!

Comment: It is slightly redundant. The .attr() and the .change() portions do the exact same thing, but to fix ie8 comp mode, its necessary to add the attr portion in.

Answer (score 2):

This seems relatively straightforward:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('select').each(
            function(){
                if ($(this).attr('onChange')) {
                    var onChangeString = $(this).attr('onChange').replace('change_option','changeoption');
                    $(this).attr('onChange',onChangeString);
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

I used the following (x)html (under a `<!DOCTYPE html>`, using Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu 10.10):

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <select onChange="change_option('SELECT___100E___7',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" name="SELECT___100E___7">
        <option value="0">dummy option 1</option>
        <option value="1">dummy option 2</option>
        <option value="2">dummy option 3</option>
        <option value="3">dummy option 4</option>
    </select>
    <select onChange="change_option('SELECT___123___6',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" name="SELECT___123___6">
        <option value="0">dummy option 1</option>
        <option value="1">dummy option 2</option>
        <option value="2">dummy option 3</option>
        <option value="3">dummy option 4</option>
    </select>
    <select onChange="change_option('SELECT___584E___52',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" name="SELECT___584E___52">
        <option value="0">dummy option 1</option>
        <option value="1">dummy option 2</option>
        <option value="2">dummy option 3</option>
        <option value="3">dummy option 4</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

[Demo at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aynfg/).

---

Edited to add an afterthought: personally, I'd **strongly** recommend removing the `onChange` event from the (x)html, and place all your behavioural logic together, rather than having it strewn around your html pages (because leaving it there leads to situations like *this*, having to manipulate a whole bunch of elements instead of rewriting one function in one file.

If you truly can't edit the html you can always use jQuery to remove the `onChange` (and `onClick` etc.) event handlers, and use a linked js file to take over their function.

Comment: Thanks for you response. However we have an issue. 1- this is basically the same as the jQuery code I have in the other thread just went about it a different way. 2- there is a javascript error in IE8 compatibility mode "Object doesn't support this property or method" This is the same error I get with my version.

Comment: @user357034, then I think you need to consider filing a bug report with the jQuery folks, or with Microsoft. It may well be a documented failing of either the library or browser, but I don't have access to a Windows installation to test, sorry.

Comment: @user357034, unfortunately that *isn't* the question you asked, here, so I didn't think to try and answer it (and without IE, I'm not really even *capable* of tracking down the reason why).

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, just kinda stumped as to why this will not work right in IE. Always something with IE, damn it!!!!

Comment: @user357034; ah, *welcome* to the *internet*, young Padewan... =)